# How do I fix the Cordova error: Failed to fetch platform <<<<< HEAD?

Tags: javascript, meteor, cordova-plugins

When trying to build my meteor app using commands:

```
meteor build ~/pesCloneBuild --server localhost:3000
```

I get the below error message:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Can anyone kindly guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: This looks like a merge conflict in the source files. Are the files version controlled?

Comment: @Philipp I merely bitBucket cloned the repository and tried running the `meteor build ~/pesCloneBuild --server localhost:3000` command. What can I do to fire this up?

Comment: You can go and try resolve the conflict yourself in this file where this `<<<<<<< HEAD` tag appears in this `addHelper.js` file.

Comment: @Philipp the **packages** folder is missing in my folder tree. How do I get around this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with meteor at all and its installation. All I can safely assume that this error message together with this `<<<<<<< HEAD` tag are a strong indictor that somewhere a merge went wrong. But I cannot tell you whose job it is to fix. But to me it seems weird that the folder doesn't exist, at least according to the console output it appears to me as if it should.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your `.meteor/platforms` file contains a merge conflict (as suggested by @Philipp). Open it in an editor and make sure it only contains valid platform names. Here is an example:

```
> cat .meteor/platforms 
browser
server
```

To learn more about this file, see https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#adding-platforms for an example of how it is used.